# I am trying to get table data from a website using python urllib and beautiful soup but it returns script

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I tried BeautifulSoup but it scrapes the script from URL.

```
url = 'https://ekartlogistics.com/shipmenttrack/FMPP0944216480' 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request, parse
read = request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(read, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

It returns the script along with other HTML scripts.

[image]

I am trying to get this table data from this URL

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is loaded data dynamically by javascript. So you can't grab data using only beautifulsoup. You can use automation tool something like selenium. Here I use selenium to mimic javascript and grab table data by using pandas as follows:

Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://ekartlogistics.com/shipmenttrack/FMPP0944216480")
time.sleep(3)
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table').get_attribute('outerHTML')

df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Date         Time       Place                           Status
0     Sunday 17 October  04:24:26 PM     Kolkata                 Shipment Created
1     Sunday 17 October  04:24:31 PM     Kolkata     Dispatched to CentralHub_BAG
2     Sunday 17 October  04:56:00 PM     Kolkata       Received at CentralHub_BAG
3     Sunday 17 October  04:56:03 PM     Kolkata       Received at CentralHub_BAG
4     Monday 18 October  03:10:35 AM       Patna     Dispatched to CentralHub_BHT
5    Tuesday 19 October  04:48:44 AM       Patna       Received at CentralHub_BHT
6    Tuesday 19 October  05:03:44 PM  Samastipur  Dispatched to SatelliteHub_SAMA
7  Wednesday 20 October  02:47:44 AM  Samastipur    Received at SatelliteHub_SAMA
8   Thursday 21 October  09:21:52 AM  Samastipur                 Out For Delivery
9     Friday 22 October  07:38:36 AM  Samastipur                        Delivered
```

Comment: Thanks, Man. I also tried some other methods like using kora.selenium and it worked but later after changing url it somehow stopped working.

Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Your Solution works perfectly fine on Google Colab as well with some minor changes. I'll be uploading my solution for Colab as well.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: THE BELOW SOLUTION IS FOR GOOGLE COLAB.

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/users/12848411/fazlul

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver') # ChromeDriver Path
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') # All above commands to install Selenium on Colab

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

wd.get("https://ekartlogistics.com/shipmenttrack/FMPP0944216480")
table = wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table').get_attribute('outerHTML')

df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Date         Time       Place                           Status
0     Sunday 17 October  04:24:26 PM     Kolkata                 Shipment Created
1     Sunday 17 October  04:24:31 PM     Kolkata     Dispatched to CentralHub_BAG
2     Sunday 17 October  04:56:00 PM     Kolkata       Received at CentralHub_BAG
3     Sunday 17 October  04:56:03 PM     Kolkata       Received at CentralHub_BAG
4     Monday 18 October  03:10:35 AM       Patna     Dispatched to CentralHub_BHT
5    Tuesday 19 October  04:48:44 AM       Patna       Received at CentralHub_BHT
6    Tuesday 19 October  05:03:44 PM  Samastipur  Dispatched to SatelliteHub_SAMA
7  Wednesday 20 October  02:47:44 AM  Samastipur    Received at SatelliteHub_SAMA
8   Thursday 21 October  09:21:52 AM  Samastipur                 Out For Delivery
9     Friday 22 October  07:38:36 AM  Samastipur                        Delivered
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try loading the page headless with Selenium and then extracting html? I also couldn't get it to work with request only.